# Why hidden subgroup problem is easy for very large subgroup?

Tags: quantum-computing, linear-algebra, quantum-information, physics, gr.group-theory

I am going through [QUANTUM MECHANICAL ALGORITHMS FOR THE
NONABELIAN HIDDEN SUBGROUP PROBLEM](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~vazirani/Papers/hidden.subgroup.pdf) by Grigni et al. On page 2, it is said that solving the hidden subgroup problem becomes very easy when the hidden subgroup is very large:

> Our lower bound on the runtime of the standard method, for subgroups of a group $G$, depends upon two parameters: the size of the hidden subgroup $H$ (naturally the problem becomes easy if $H$ is very large), and $c(G)$, the number of conjugacy classes in $G$. We give a lower bound showing that approximately $\left(\frac{\sqrt{|G|}}{|H|\sqrt{c(G)}}\right)^{1/3}$ rounds of Fourier sampling are required before the standard method can identify $H$.

**My questions:**

1. Why is it easy?
2. How large is 'very large'?

**My effort:**
Let the group be $G$ and the subgroup be $H$. One could argue that If any $g \in G$ is found to be in $H$ we know that all $g^n$ are in $H$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. So we can skip them and check other group elements of $G$. But how do we know that determining $g^n$'s is cheaper than feeding them to the quantum circuit?

Comment: Large objects are difficult to hide, no?

Comment: You can find a generating set for $H$ whp with a (non-quantum) randomized algorithm just by taking $\mathrm{poly}([G:H])$ random samples from $G$, and keeping those that are in $H$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, what does the quantity $[G:H]$ mean?

Comment: @OmarShehab: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_a_subgroup